# static_assert unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

I have an overloaded `operator&` for my class where I do a static assert if the parameter is a pointer.

```
class test {
public:

  template<typename T>
  friend inline test& operator&(test& so, T const& t) {
    std::cout << "is_pointer : " << std::is_pointer<T>::value << std::endl;
    static_assert(std::is_pointer<T>::value, "no operator overloaded for pointers.");
    
    // some stuff
  }
};
```

If I use this operator I always get the assertion even if the type is definitively not a pointer. `std::cout << "is_pointer : " << std::is_pointer<T>::value << std::endl;` is printing a zero...

```
int main() {
  test t;
  t & 123;
  return 0;
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/yqHSZ4).

Comment: Quick hint for printing booleans: `std::cout << std::boolalpha;` before you do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course the assertion fails. You're requiring that the type `T` is a pointer, but `T` here is an `int`.

Perhaps you meant the following?

```
// Ensure that `T` is not a pointer
static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>::value, "no operator overloaded for pointers");
```

Assertions are statements that *ensure* a particular condition. It's not quite "if X then output error message Y"; in fact, it's the exact opposite. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are asserting that the type passed *is* a pointer. If you pass something which is *not* a pointer, the `static_assert()` fails and you get a message. It seems, you want to precisely negate the condition as you do *not* want to work with pointers:

```
static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>::value, "no operator overloaded for pointers.");
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want this to compile if and only if `T` *is not* a pointer.  In your original expression, you assert that `T` *is* a pointer.

Basically, the `static_assert` means, "My first argument better be true, otherwise I will complain at compile time with the second argument as error message."

What you seem to want:

```
class test {
public:

  template<typename T>
  friend inline test& operator&(test& so, T const& t) {
    static_assert(! std::is_pointer<T>::value, "no operator overloaded for pointers.");

    // some stuff
  }
};
```

Comment: `I can't comment, so I have to answer instead.` Actually the intention is that you don't comment _at all_ until you have the required rep, rather than going against the rules and finding any old inappropriate place to post your words. I'll let you off though, because this is a good answer and actually is an answer. :)